# Javascript data structure (streamed by a websocket connection) including an array where I would expect a key

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, websocket

I've been receiving the type of data structure below (from a websocket connection)

```
{
    [String: '0.01234567']
    _int: {
        [String: '1234567'] _s: 0,
        _d: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    },
    _precision: 8
}
```

This doesn't look like anything I've seen before, looks like a poorly build JSON. Am I missing something here?

The information I would like to access is `0.01234567` but I'm quite confused with the way this output is structured. Do I need to parse the string myself or is there a quick and painless way to collect that info?

Answer (score 0):

its not valid json so it looks like you must handle it as a string.